# Multiple Lambda expressions or Help identifing what this line of code is

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I am trying to figure out what this expression is:

```
allFeatures =
    wellLayer.QueryTools.GetAllFeatures(ReturningColumnsType.AllColumns);

searchResults =
    allFeatures.Where(f => f.ColumnValues["LEASE_NAME"].ToLower()
                            .Contains(searchQuery.ToLower())).ToList();
```

I was also wondering if there is a way to make this expression get multiple values - not only "LEASE_NAME" but a few others.

Comment: allFeatures in a collection of objects. Then the LINQ simply says "Select ONLY those where Lease name contains the string searchquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get multiple values, try this

```
searchResults =
allFeatures.Where(f => f.ColumnValues["LEASE_NAME"].ToLower()
                        .Contains(searchQuery.ToLower()) || 
                        f.ColumnValues["SOMEOTHER_NAME"].ToLower()
                        .Contains(searchQuery.ToLower()) ||
                        f.ColumnValues["YETANOTHER_NAME"].ToLower()
                        .Contains(searchQuery.ToLower())).ToList();`
```

You can use the OR (||) and add as many values as you would like.

Comment: thank you so much, and while im here can you tell me what this is? i am new to mvc and C# and pretty much everything else. is this a Lamda expression or what?

Comment: @user1650547 This is Linq, using a lambda expression. I recommend doing some googling, but [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33769/Basics-of-LINQ-Lamda-Expressions) is a site with a basic overview. If this answer helped, please feel free to accept/upvote it.